# Unable to connect to openvpn with saved password "auth-users-pass"

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to save the username, and password of my `openvpn` client in '`.secret.txt`', and I'm receiving errors when attempting to connect, or the password is requested, instead of being read from '`.secret.txt`'

Here is my config file:

```
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server_4EBX2EpXPZasiTv1 name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>
auth-user-pass //root/.secret.txt
```

When connecting, i'm receiving errors:

> WARNING: file '//root//secret.txt' is group or others accessible

Comment: Look at the unix command "chmod". You'll want something like "chmod 700 secret.txt" - 700 being full permissions to root, none to group, none to other, but you may need to tweak that - 600 perhaps. read the documentation for required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

`WARNING: file '//root//secret.txt' is group or others accessible`

I was able to resolve with `chmod 600`.

However, the connection still prompts for a password:

`Wed Aug  8 07:44:22 2018 OpenVPN 2.4.3 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul  3 2017
Wed Aug  8 07:44:22 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Enter Private Key Password:`

`